# Не запускается jar - Exception in Application start method. Но из под IJ нормально в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, jar

Не запускается jar - Exception in Application start method. Но из под IJ нормально в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

вы не указали путь к библиотеке(ам) и запускаете из папки `target`. IJ запускает проекты из корня, только не `jar` файлы. Из корня вы можете запустить ваш jar указав путь и поместив библиотеки в переменную classpath.